# Post request for CI4 Unit testing

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have the following code running in CI 4.1.2:

```
public function testForgotten(){

    fwrite(STDERR,"\n\nProcess Forgotten:\n");

    $_COOKIE[csrf_token()] = csrf_hash();

    $result = $this->post('site/forgotten',array(
        'Username'      => 'my@email.com',
        csrf_token()        => csrf_hash(),
    ));

    print'<pre>';print_r($result->response());print'</pre>';

    $result->assertRedirect();
}
```

As you can see I simply want to check if the forgotten password form/page is working. However the output of `$result->response()` includes the unposted to page along with `<form action="http://example.com/site/forgotten" id="Config\Forms::reset" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">` as part of the form (noting **I've not put in the example.com - Codeigniter did that!** So just wondering what I'm missing in terms of getting this test to run/work?

FYI I'm running under a PHAR file with `php punit.phar tests/app/Controllers/SiteTests.php` which works fine when running simple `get('/path/to/page');` calls.

I have since found the example.com can be changed in `phpunit.xml.dist` but this has still not fixed the assertRedirect issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer appears to be that CI4 does not actually populate the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables rather its own internal mechanism. This becomes apparent when you use:

```
$request = \Config\Services::request();

print_r($request->getPost('Username'));
```

Instead of `$_POST`.

The solution is either a) use the `getPost()` type functions or b) amend the framework (yes shock/horror!) in `system/HTTP/RequestTrait.php` and `setGlobal` to include:

```
switch ($method){
    case 'post': $_POST = $value; break;
    case 'get': $_GET = $value; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is a working solution for [Testing Controllers](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/testing/controllers.html#) ONLY. Not  for [HTTP Testing](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/testing/feature.html).

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
/**
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function testForgotten()
{
    fwrite(STDERR, "\n\nProcess Forgotten:\n");

    $_COOKIE[csrf_token()] = csrf_hash();

    $request = $this->request
        ->withMethod('post')
        // parameter 'post' for post method parameters
        ->setGlobal('post', [
            'Username' => 'my@email.com',
            csrf_token() => csrf_hash()
        ]);

    $result = $this
        ->withRequest($request)
        ->controller(YourSiteController::class)
        ->execute('forgotten');

    print'<pre>';
    print_r($result->response());
    print'</pre>';

    $result->assertRedirect();
}
```

Key-points to note:

1. Use `$request = $this->request;`, then chain it by `withMethod()` and `setGlobal()` for adapting POST request method and accepting POST request parameters;
2. Bind the `$request` variable by `$this->withRequest($request)`;
3. Chain `$this->withRequest($request)` by `controller()` and `execute()` to get the result.